# How to trim a file name to not exceed the maximum file path size

Tags: c#, string, path

I am making an image downloader that should be able to name a downloaded file with tags. However, sometimes there are too many tags and I get an exception because the filename is too long.

The file path is: my .exe path + ./out/ directory + tags + extension

I want a piece of code that would let me trim a filename string if its full path exceeds the maximum length and keep an extension.

I have already got some code but it doesn't work properly and I don't think it is clean enough.

```cs
string Truncate(string value, int maxChars)
{
    return value.Length <= maxChars ? value : value.Substring(0, maxChars) + "...";
}
```

```cs
private async void downloadImage(string url, string tags, string rating)
        {
            string fullpath = "./out/" + rating + tags + ExtFromURL(url);
            string regexSearch = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
            Regex r = new Regex(string.Format("[{0}]", Regex.Escape(regexSearch)));
            fullpath = r.Replace(fullpath, "");

            string shortPath = Path.GetFullPath("./out/" + rating + ExtFromURL(url));
            string extension = fullpath.Substring(fullpath.Length - 5);
            if (fullpath.Length > 259)
                fullpath = Truncate(fullpath, 259 - shortPath.Length - 4);
            try
            {
                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; " +
                                      "Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
                    await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new System.Uri(url), fullpath + extension);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nitpicking but caller fuction should not have to handle the size of the elipse string you add ( the "..."), as it's something the caller do not know about. If you change the ellipse, are you going to go throught all call to change -4 to -8? `private string Truncate(string input, int lenght, string ellipse = "...")
            => (input.Length < lenght ? input : input.Substring(0, lenght - ellipse.Length) + ellipse);`

Answer (score 2):

> The file path is: my .exe path + ./out/ directory + tags + extension

There is no sensible way to do that. If you do not want your filename to get to long, just do not add stuff to it in the first place. But even then it might be to long, because someone picked a really, really long path as their out directory.

Usually such directories are in the user profile. While that makes the very reliable place to have write rights, that also makes it exceeding propable the fully qualified path is to long. I have been running into lenght issues just making backup copies of those folders!

This is a plain old [Exogenous excetpions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/). There is nothing you can do about it, except catching it and telling the user about it. As long as the user can pick the out folder - and maybe wich tags to add - this is not jour problem to fix.

But do take care to only catch the *exact exceptions* you can *actually* handle. [catch (Exception ex)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET) should be avoided in production code.

Comment: But can I just use some while loop in order to shorten a string? I understand that there will be fewer tags if I do that, but I think it's better than nothing.

Comment: @РусланИсаев Just allow the user to select wich tags to use. Then he can shorten it and still knows what it is named. Most backup software and CD digitizer software uses this pattern | "Noting is quite as dumb, as code that tries to be smart." Automatically shortening the string with a loop? Entirely possible. But it also *is* trying to be smart.

Comment: In my case I think it's better and easier to just automatically shorten the string. Can you please give me some code?  I could not figure out how to do that

Comment: @РусланИсаев You are appending tags to the filename, right? If so, try it once with the tags added. Once without the tags. If that also fails, it is the users job to find a proper folder to store stuff in. | Ideally the UI to select the folder and/or startup, should check if the set folder is useable for names with/without the tag.